# CSUF EPP - What are your thoughts ( trouble adding to the end of linkedlist)

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

SO community I will be attending CSUF in January of 2020. As a requirement for all CS students at this Cal State, you have to take an exam to progress to upper-division classes. The University posted a sample one on their site.

I am trying to get a head start on this and complete the sample exam and start reviewing any other topics I might need. I have been doing well through the exam so far, but I ran into a problem with my second problem.

**problem2:**  https://i.stack.imgur.com/GO1pa.png

I have accessed all the resources they state in the problem except for *IntListNode.cpp*

Resources provided: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqpfP.png

As the problem states, I started creating *AddAtPosition(int elem, int pos)*

```
void IntegerListt::AddAtPosition(int elem, int pos) {

    if(pos == 0)
    {
        addFront(elem);
    }else if (pos >= size())
    {
        IntListNode* temp = head;
        while(temp != NULL)
        {
            if(temp->getNext() == NULL)
            {
                IntListNode* newElem = new IntListNode(elem, NULL);
                temp->getNext() = newElem;
            }
            temp = temp->getNext();
        }

    }
```

**This is not a complete function:** 
I have only accounted for a position [0] and position >= size()..

My goal is to add a node to the end of the list.

I have tried using a wide variety of different ways to get around this, but seem to get stuck.

*Resources*

http://www.fullerton.edu/ecs/cs/resources/files/test.cpp

http://www.fullerton.edu/ecs/cs/resources/files/IntegerList.cpp

http://www.fullerton.edu/ecs/cs/resources/files/IntegerList.h

http://www.fullerton.edu/ecs/cs/resources/files/IntListNode.h

-I have not modified anything on the resources... only added my function to add an element-

I also understand that

`temp->getNext() = newElem;`

It is not possible, because getNext() returns a value and is not assignable, but I can't find a way to do so without modifying the code.

TL;DR

I am trying to add a node at the end of the list using the resources provided to me and without modifying them, but I feel the resources provided to me won't help me accomplish this unless I modify.

My progress is the function above.

Comment: Kai, that extra 't' was purposely added.

Comment: `*GetNext()` returns the `next` as a pointer, not as a value. Does `tempNext = temp->getNext(); tempNext = newElem` not work?

Comment: Kai, that would not work because it will lose the connection to the original linked list (the linked list I want to add to). Another issue I see is that you're assigning tempNext to NULL.

Comment: If `GetNext() == NULL` it's at the end of the list and wouldn't lose the connection. The previous node would still point to it. newElem should point to null, it's the end.

Comment: tempNext=temp->getNext() // tempNext=NULL, and newElim is a new node that is not attached to any linked list. having tempNext = newElim, would mean tempNext is now apart newElim linked list which is just the solo node. I have to get the next pointer to POINT to newElim instead of NULL..

Comment: Hmm, you really need the address of `*next` and I don't see how you get it. You could walk through the entire list and re-build it with the new node

Comment: You might want to review [ask]. It is better to begin your question with the actual question. Especially since I am having trouble finding a question in your post. (If your mini life story is relevant, it is likely more suitable as an end note than as the first few paragraphs.) Focused, specific questions are better than posts that warrant a "TL;DR" section.

Comment: HINT: Try writing a member function `addAfter(int elem, IntListNode* p)` that inserts a new element (containing `elem`) after the node pointed to by `p`.

Answer (score 0):

In IntListNode.h

```
void setNext(IntListNode* newnext) { next = newnext; }
```

In IntegerList.cpp

```
if(temp->getNext() == NULL) {
    IntListNode* newElem = new IntListNode(elem, NULL);
    temp->setNext(newElem);
}
```

Comment: I understand that, but they also provide a method called getNext() that retrieves 'next', but I get an error when using this function.

Comment: Agreed Kai. I am not using it the way Girspoon has implied above.

Comment: I'm unable to add comments to the main post, sorry for the dumb answer. Are you allowed to add a setter to IntListNode.h?